# @try fails to catch EXC_I386_GPFLT?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, nslog

I have a simple wrapper for NSLogv. It works fine, except throws an exception if there are too many placeholders in the format string. I would like to catch that exception, but this `@try` block doesn't work. Why?

```
- (void)error:(NSString *)formatString, ...;
{
    @try {
        va_list arglist;
        va_start(arglist, formatString);
        formatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR: %@", formatString];
        NSLogv(formatString, arglist);
        va_end(arglist);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
       // Handle exception ...
    }
}
```

Here is an example that throws an exception:

```
[[MYLogger error:@"%@ %@", value];
```

Comment: Why catch the exception? You want it to crash since it is a programmer bug. Find and fix the issue in development and testing.

Comment: `@try` in Objective-C should only be used to "fail gracefully" when an exception occurs.  It's not intended to be used casually like Java exceptions are.

Comment: Catching this exception is last line of defense; I don't want app crashing because of an error log statement that had wrong number of placeholders.

Comment: @PhilMitchell That's what testing is for. Besides, you should probably compile out the logs for a distribution build.

Comment: @rmaddy Appreciate the input. It's true that NSLogv will never get called in production, but remote logger will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@try catches exceptions. You are trying to catch a signal.

My advice: Don't even try.

Comment: Having the same issue. No problems at hardware devices but having this issue when testing on simulator. Any update?